# Append text to input after selecting one from list

Tags: ractivejs

```
<input type="submit" on-click='toggle("Dropdown")'>
<input type="text" value="{{category.name}}">
{{#if Dropdown}}
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" on-click="select">Custard Pudding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" on-click="select">Coffee Pudding</a></li>
    </ul>

{{/if}}

ractive.on('select', function(event) {

    this.observe( 'category.name', function ( newValue, keypath ) {
        this.set( keypath, '' + newValue );
    });
})
```

Understand that in JQuery `$('dropdown a').text()` and append it to input would work.
Only question I have is how to grab the text and set it to input when on-click "select". Searched example and tried but it is not doing anything. Perhaps the way is wrong.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from `event.node`:

```
ractive.on('select', function(event) {
    this.set( 'category.name', '' + event.node.textContent );
})
```

You could do that inline too:

```
<li><a href="#" on-click="set('category.name', '' + event.node.textContent)">Custard Pudding</a></li>
```

But if the `<li>` are generated from data (or you could make it that way) you can set directly

```
<input type="submit" on-click='toggle("Dropdown")'>
<input type="text" value="{{category.name}}">
{{#if Dropdown}}
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      {{#each ['Custard Pudding', 'Coffee Pudding'] }}
      <li><a href="#" on-click="set('category.name', this)">{{this}}</a></li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

{{/if}}
```

Comment: thanks for help but one question - how not to show "{{category.name}}" text on input as I noticed on other examples. I will try your example, hopefully it works